# What is the C# Regex equivalent to Java's appendReplacement and appendTail

Tags: c#, java, regex

**UPDATE**

Here is what I came up with. I haven't tested it yet because it is part of a much larger piece of code that still needs to be ported.

Can you see anything that looks out of place?

```
private const string tempUserBlock = "%%%COMPRESS~USER{0}~{1}%%%";
string html = "some html";
int p = 0;
var userBlock = new ArrayList();

MatchCollection matcher = preservePatterns[p].Matches(html);
int index = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int lastValue = 0;

foreach(Match match in matcher){
    string matchValue = match.Groups[0].Value;

    if(matchValue.Trim().Length > 0) {
        userBlock.Add(matchValue);

        int curIndex = lastValue + match.Index;
        sb.Append(html.Substring(lastValue, curIndex));
        sb.AppendFormat(tempUserBlock, p, index++);

        lastValue = curIndex + match.Length;
    }
}

sb.Append(html.Substring(lastValue));
html = sb.ToString();
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST BELOW:**

Here is the original Java:

```
private static final String tempUserBlock = "%%%COMPRESS~USER{0}~{1}%%%";
String html = "some html";
int p = 0;
List<String> userBlock = new ArrayList<String>();

Matcher matcher = patternToMatch.matcher(html);
int index = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find())
{
    if (matcher.group(0).trim().length() > 0)
    {
        userBlock.add(matcher.group(0));
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, MessageFormat.format(tempUserBlock, p, index++));
    }
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
html = sb.toString();
```

And my C# conversion so far

```
private const string tempUserBlock = "%%%COMPRESS~USER{0}~{1}%%%";
string html = "some html";
int p = 0;
var userBlock = new ArrayList();

MatchCollection matcher = preservePattern.Matches(html);
int index = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(var i = 0; i < matcher.Count; ++i){
    string match = matcher[i].Groups[0].Value;
    if(match.Trim().Length > 0) {
        userBlock.Add(match);
        // WHAT DO I DO HERE?
        sb.Append( string.Format(tempUserBlock, p, index++) );            
    }
}
// WHAT DO I DO HERE?
matcher.appendTail(sb);
html = sb.toString();
```

**See comment above, where I ask, "WHAT DO I DO HERE?"**

***Clarification***
The Java code above is performing string replacement on some HTML. It saves the originally replaced text because it needs to be re-inserted later after some whitespace compression is completed.

Comment: Can you better define the issue, like, what is the expected result and what is the result you're getting?

Comment: I'm guessing its the parts marked with `// WHAT DO I DO HERE?`

Comment: Can you post the full code, it's hard to help with the line below "what do I do here" (which I assume is the question) when we don't know what p or tempUserBlock are

Comment: From my very limited understanding of Java I look at this code and I see two notions that should never be seen together: HTML and Regex. If this code is doing what I think it does (parsing HTML with Regex) I would strongly recommend you profiting from the occasion of rewriting this code to do it properly i.e. using a html parser like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader). Forget about those regexes, stringbuilders, and string trimmings. Do it the right way.

Comment: @Darin, I agree with you; but this is supposed to be a quick port of a HTML/CSS/Javascript compressor already written in Java.

Comment: You will have to make your own `append*` function by using the Match's `Index`, `Length`, and `Result`.

Comment: @Gabe: I think that is what I've done; but I used string.Format instead of Regex.Resul. Care to take a look and tell me if you think its okay?

Comment: @David Murdoch - quick question mate, what's the software you're porting? quote: a quick port of a HTML/CSS/Javascript compressor".

Comment: I can't remember of the top of my head...why do you ask?

Comment: @David Murdoch - curious :) I helped port YUICompressor from Java => .NET and what your doing is very similar to some YUICompressor java code i'm (struggling) to read. So i was curious to what this question was regarding :)

Comment: It seems that you are porting Google's [htmlcompressor](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) library. Would it be possible to get the (partial) source code of your work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember what project this was for, so I can't get you the code. I'm sure there are lots of other C# HTML Compressors out there nowadays to choose from though.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I've thought that, too ;-) Seems I was wrong. So I'm starting porting it, too.

Comment: Just a reminder: the bytes-over-the-wire savings you'll get by compressing your HTML is VERY minimal if you are already sending it gzipped. Focus on getting your PageSpeed scores in the 90s before spending too much time on compressing HTML. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMurdoch Actually this will ship in our Desktop CMS that produces static HTML pages so we have to do it in our application, and cannor rely on IIS/Apache.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I've [finished my porting](http://blog.magerquark.de/c-port-of-googles-htmlcompressor-library/), if anyone might be interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to reproduce Java's `appendReplacement/appendTail` functionality; .NET has something better: [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx).  Check it out:

```
string holder = "Element {0} = {1}";
string s0 = "111 222 XYZ";
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

string s1 = Regex.Replace(s0, @"\d+",
  m => string.Format(holder, arr.Add(m.Value), m.Value)
);

Console.WriteLine(s1);
foreach (string s in arr)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

output:

```
Element 0 = 111 Element 1 = 222 XYZ
111
222
```

There are several ways to implement the MatchEvaluator, all thoroughly discussed in [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/91/Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressions-in-CSharp).  This one (lambda expressions) is by far the coolest.

Comment: I'll check it out in the morning. +1 for programming based on "coolness."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Java regex classes, but this is my C# interpretation of what I think your code does:

```
private const string tempUserBlock = "%%%COMPRESS~USER{0}~{1}%%%"; 
string html = "some html"; 
int p = 0; 
var userBlock = new List<string>(); 

MatchCollection matcher = preservePattern.Matches(html); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
int last = 0;
foreach (Match m in matcher)
{
    string match = m.Groups[0].Value; 
    if(match.Trim().Length > 0) { 
        userBlock.Add(match); 
        sb.Append(html.Substring(last, m.Index - last));
        sb.Append(m.Result(string.Format(tempUserBlock, p, index++)));
    }
    last = m.Index + m.Length;
}
sb.Append(html.Substring(last));
html = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: awesome, that is almost exactly what I came up with! You put the m.Index + m.Length in the correct place. Thanks. I'll let you know how it performs in a bit.